# Crunching Fabric Answers Data

Tags: analytics, google-fabric

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't figure out how to dive deeper into the Answers Events to gain more insights.

For instance, I would like to cross-reference users that were retained after 3 weeks to see how many of a KPI they had. Or see which events high-engagement users had. Is this type of work possible at all?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Answers is focused on being real-time and opinionated so this type of deeper dive isn't currently possible. Good to know what you'd like to do!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Mike. I really like the API and integrating it to my app as been a breeze. I'm looking forward to seeing where you all take this.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, Unrelated but where can I go to troubleshoot events/answers that spike really high, but we only call it once!

Comment: Sorry, not quite following @KyleBrowning, can you share more?